# Remove the [ ] brackets from the JSON response file so that it can be pushed to elasticsearch as a single doc

Tags: arrays, json, elasticsearch, formatting, kibana

My data  is a single doc per  line and my doc has many fields for the bulkrequest in elasticsearch.

Output I'm getting :

```
 [{"name":"asd ","id":"993501","section":"E","marks":" 52 "},
 {"name":"abc ","id":"9261","section":"E","marks":" 25 "},
 {"name":"xyz ","id":"9901","section":"E","marks":" 50 "}]
```

Output I want :

```
 {"name":"asd ","id":"993501","section":"E","marks":" 52 "},
 {"name":"abc ","id":"9261","section":"E","marks":" 25 "},
 {"name":"xyz ","id":"9901","section":"E","marks":" 50 "}
```